# Eclipse Compare Editor closes after saving

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

I use Eclipse 4.3.2 with Subversive 1.1.3.

When I try to compare a folder with another branch (Left click on that folder -> Compare With -> Branch), Eclipse shows a Compare Editor but when I import a modification and save that change (Ctrl+S), the Compare Editor closes itself so no more comparisons are possible.
How can I prevent this behaviour (non errors are logged from Eclipse)?

Using Compare Ediotr from "Syncronize with Repository" works perfectly not closing the window after saving the imported modifications.

Thanks
Andrea

Comment: Same problem here with Eclipse Kepler SR1. It's really annoying, specially when you have to backport quite a lot of source code.